# Silverlight 4 - Retrieve a solid color brush from Resource Dictionary at runtime?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, resourcedictionary

I am trying to retrieve a solid color brush pre-defined in a resource dictionary (Styles.xaml) from C#.

The problem is that when i run the following code nothing happens:

```
private void LinkContinue_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.LinkContinue.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["HoverColorBrush"];
}
```

However if I set the background in code explicitly it runs fine:

```
private void LinkContinue_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.LinkContinue.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the casting successfully returns a solicColorBrush?
Or there maybe there is an exception thrown?

Comment: Is `Resources["HoverColorBrush"]` `null` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer was `Application.Current.Resources["ResourceName"] as SolidColorBrush`! Who would've known that the Resources object points to the resource dictionary for the page? UGHHH

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `Resources["HoverColorBrush"]` looks up a resource stored in the resources of **the current object**.  In this case, the resources of the instance of the class that contains the method `LinkContinue_MouseEnter`.

If you want to use the same lookup mechanism that `{StaticResource HoverColorBrush}` would use, you need to use the `FindResource` method instead:

- [`FrameworkElement.FindResource Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx)

But, as luck would have it, Silverlight does not support `FindResource` and so you need to either look up the resource directly in the `ResourceDictionary` defined in `Styles.xaml`, or roll your own `FindResource`.

Here is a blog article on this topic with sample code:

- [A FindResource implementation for Silverlight](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2011/01/findresource-implementation-for.html)